# Is there any mechanism to secure my .mdf files in SQL Server Express 2008?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008

I have developed C# and SQL Server Express database project. Can I secure from copying and pasting my `.mdf` file? Is there any way to protect my `.mdf` file from being watched the schema? So no one could see the functions and tables of my database? No detaching or attaching it to other instances? Do you have any ideas how to do or any ready mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used DbDefence in my project. I am satisfied with security now. It has one minus - free version allows only encrypt 77Mb, which is eniugh in my project. If you want to more, you can purchase commercial one. Very easy to install and to use. 
You can find more information here http://www.dbdefence.com/index.php
If you need any help, please contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my question at: [deploy SQL Server Database with a Winforms app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3846081/337294).

I ended up using [SQL Server CE](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx) and I'm perfectly happy with it. No SQL Server installation needed (just a couple of additional dlls). And you can set password for your database as well. If you're using Winforms, there are a couple of glitches. But workarounds for each one can be found with a simple googling.

Comment: But I have scalar value functions and stored procedures, which is not possible in CE or SQLite. What do you recommend? What about DBDefence? Have any one used it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with DBDefence. But it seems promising.

Comment: It is a little bit complicated, I could not use it in my project! I will try to find out new approach.